# Change tab text color when selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to change the tab text color when it's selected.

[image: tab example]

I tried with a selector XML, but nothing happened. I'm using this library: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet

```
 prevTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();// Keep track of the default tab
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener(){ //tabhost is a variable of type TabHost, which will contain all your tabs
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String id) {
            int tab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
            TextView tv = (TextView) getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);//Set selected tab colour to something you want

            if(prevTab!=-1){// If there was a previously selected tab, set it back to a default colour as it is now unselected
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) getTabWidget().getChildAt(prevTab).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            prevTab = tab; //Update this newly selected tab to the currently selected tab, for same logic to repeat for future tab changes
        }
    });
```

Put this code snippet in your *onCreate()* method after all tab related initializations are done.

Answer (score -1):

```
tab.setTextColor(tabTextColor);
```